# Where's the Magnetic Field?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I want to evolve my Charjabug, but I'm not sure which area is the supposed regional Magnetic Field. So, uh, where is it?

Comment: It appears most overworld evolutionary requirements have been replaced with stones. Leafeon and Glaceon got the same treatment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can evolve it with a thunder stone according to [kagster123](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78165254)(GameFaqs) and [tebacon](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonSwordAndShield/comments/dxaxow/where_is_the_special_magnetic_field_to_evolve/) (Reddit).